# Launch Remote Desktop from Silverlight Application

Tags: c#, silverlight, remote-desktop

I want to launch the regular Remote Desktop popup to a specified ip adress from a Silverlight Application run inside the browser. (OOB is not a solution :( ) I can't seem to find a solution for this anywhere. 
I wanted to use Process.Start and use mstsc.exe but i can't seem to find out how to start a process from inside Silverlight...

Comment: You *don't* want Silverlight to support this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative solution.

What about to generate [*.rdp file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg156129%28v=winembedded.70%29.aspx)?

User will automatically download them and can start start his remote session by double click on this downloaded file.

Comment: That's definately a diffrent approach - thanks for it!